# Question about a step in the proof of the bracket process

Tags: stochastic-processes

Let's first state the theorem

> $\forall M$ continuous local martingale, there exists a unique increasing continuous process $\langle M\rangle $ zero at $t=0$ and such that $M^2-\langle M \rangle $ is again a continuous local martingale. Further for all stopping times $\tau$, we have $\langle M^\tau\rangle = \langle M \rangle^\tau$.

The last statement is not clear for me. I know that $L:=M^2-\langle M \rangle $ is a local martingale. Then we look at $L^\tau=(M^\tau)^2-\langle M \rangle^\tau $, and we apply the stopping theorem. Why do we can apply the stopping theorem? For that, $L$ should be uniformly integrable, or $\tau$ must be finite?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to use is that the set of local martingales are stable under stopping, i.e. $M^\tau$ is local martingale if $M$ is a local martingale and $\tau$ is any stopping time. Then
$$
(M^{\tau})^2-\langle M\rangle^\tau=(M^2-\langle M\rangle)^{\tau}
$$
yields the result.

Comment: Just a small question after a while. Why are local martingales stable under stopping? Thank you for your help

Comment: Simply because martingales are stable under stopping.

Comment: But this is just, as far as I know, true if $\tau$ is bounded or the martingale is uniformly integrable?

Comment: It is true for a general $\tau$, but it's true that it uses the optional sampling theorem on the bounded stopping time $\tau\wedge t$.